# Is it possible to integrate windows 10 share apis in a desktop app(not an Universal App)? If yes, how?

Tags: share, desktop-application, windows-10, win-universal-app, charms-bar

I have a desktop project written in C++ and I have share my media through Facebook, Twitter or any other sharing apps installed on my machine using windows sharing option(Charm bar as in Win 8.1). Can I do that or I need to convert my app to Windows Universal App.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like the ShareTarget/DataTransfer APIs are available in the API set that's tagged as being [okay to use from Desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn554295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so it looks like you're out of luck for now.